# How to sort an array whose sorting order is in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
// 0 =  eldest = pre
//everytime i run this code i get names in pattern that makes no sense to me

public class cousin {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] children = {"Arm", "Jo", "Ra", "Jas", "Pre", "She"};

        int[] sortAge =          {2, 4, 3, 5, 0, 1};

        int x = 0;
        int y = 1;


        while ( x < 6)
        {
            int ref = sortAge[x];   
            System.out.print(y+ "\t");
            System.out.println(children[ref]);
            x = x + 1;
            y = y + 1;      }

    }

}
```

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Java is an object-oriented language. **Use it!** That means, create an class `Child` with two field: `name` and `age`. Now you can sort a `Child[]` using [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-), and the values stay together.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the `children` be sorted according to the position in the `sortAge`. Try the code below

```
String[] children = {"Arm", "Jo", "Ra", "Jas", "Pre", "She"};
int[] sortAge = {2, 4, 3, 5, 0, 1};

String[] sortedChildren = new String[children.length];      
for (int x = 0; x < children.length; x++) {
    int ref = sortAge[x];   
    sortedChildren[ref] = children[x];   
}

for (int y = 0; y < sortedChildren.length; y++) {
    System.out.println((y + 1) + "\t" + sortedChildren[y]);
}
```

The output is

```
1   Pre
2   She
3   Arm
4   Ra
5   Jo
6   Jas
```

Comment: And what would happen if the ages were, say, `{3, 9, 12, 9, 4, 7, 2}`?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson The ```sortAge``` is the array of index, that is a permutation of {0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N}.

Answer (score 0):

This is the output I got,

1
Ra
2
Pre
3
Jas
4
She
5
Arm
6
Jo

You would be getting this since in your array since the first spot of sortAge is 2 and children[2] is "Ra", then the second spot of sortAge is 4 and children[4] is Pre etc.

Since you said Pre is the oldest (because of the 0 in sortAge), you will have to check which spot the lowest number in sortAge is, and keep track of that.  Then use that as your "ref" variable to display the child's name.  You can then remove the 0 from the sortAge array and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and got them in the order I would expect:

```
1   Ra
2   Pre
3   Jas
4   She
5   Arm
6   Jo
```

I'm guessing that you're trying to output each child in the first array in order based on the numbers in the second array, where each number in the second array is the index you want them to be at in the output.

### What Your Code Does

What your code currently does is loop through the array sortAge and print out which child is at the index found in sortAge in order. In order to put the children in the correct order using your algorithm, you would need to give it the input `sortAge = {4,5,0,2,1,3}`, which says that the oldest child is at index 4 (Pre), followed by the child at index 5 (She), etc.

### One Possible Solution

In order to get the output you want from your input, you need to first loop through to sort the children's names and then print it out in the sorted order (since it would be very inefficient to try to actually find each child's name in the output order).

This requires you to create a new array of sorted children by looping through them in order and putting them at the index where you want them like this:

```
String[] sortedList = new String[children.length];
for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    sortedList[sortAge[i]] = children[i];
}
```

Then you can print out each item in the sorted array by looping through them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + "\t" + sortedList[i]);
}
```

This will give you the output:

```
1   Pre
2   She
3   Arm
4   Ra
5   Jo
6   Jas
```